Mozilla Firefox Proxy Authentication Popup
I was wondering if its somehow possible to create an automated process to login to my destined Firefox proxy. Every time I try connecting to the proxy Mozilla expects me to manually type in the login information for every session I start. For your information I am using Java, and selenium for this project. Any help of any kind would be great.
I did attempt to use an extension to solve this problem, but I was kind of having issues with it. I think the extension is called SwitchyOmega.

I figured it out. I created a custom Firefox extension that's capable of reading what proxy that is randomly selected from my Java application and automatically authenticates from there.
